Are modern depictions of the Temple Mount erroneous by showing only One Temple Building, since Jesus said "buildings" (plural)?
We read of the Temple in the opening verses of the Olivet Discourse, which enthralled the disciples very much. But when the Temple Mount was spoken of, a plural "buildings" was used:

And Jesus went out, and departed from the Temple; and His disciples came to Him to show Him the buildings of the Temple. And Jesus said unto them, "See all these things? Verily, I say unto you, There shall not be left here one stone upon another, that shall not be thrown down. (Matthew 24:1-2)


And as He went out of the Temple, one of His disciples said unto Him, "Master, see what manner of stones and what buildings are here!" And Jesus answering, said unto him, "Seest thou these great buildings? There shall not be left one stone upon another, that shall not be thrown down." (Mark 13:1-2)

So then, is there reason to only show the Temple proper (and Solomon's portico, often), without any other buildings on the Mount? Many pictures do depict the "Court of the Priests" as joined in front of the Temple, but the use of plural "buildings" by Jesus and the disciples seems to indicate other structures! Should they also be drawn in, as well?
BE.SE ExampleFor a clear example of this tendency see BE.SE #66108 ! Where, besides the Temple proper (with its adjoining court), the rest of the Temple platform is void of the buildings that Jesus mentioned.
[See depictions at: The New Bible Dictionary, ed. J.D.Douglas, 1962 "Temple", p. 1246.New Manners and Customs of Bible Times, ed. Ralph Gower, 1897, p. 350Macmillan Bible Atlas, Aharoni & Avi-yonah, 1969, p. 149.New Bible Atlas, D.R.W. Wod, 1985, p. 104, 109Illustrated Dictionary & Concordance of the Bible, 1986, ed. Geoffrey Wigoder, G.G. The Jerusalem    Publ. House Ltd.]
Keep in mind that the Temple compound was around 35 acres in size; plenty of room for other "buildings" beside the Temple proper, to be built. (K.E. Bailey, Jesus Through Middle Eastern Eyes: Cultural Studies in the Gospels (2008), pp. 232-233, IVP) To put this in perspective, my Church is situated on 33 acres containing two large Domes, 4 college dormitories, college library, administration building, chapel, basketball gym, maintenance offices, soccer field, elementary play ground, and 2 huge parking lots!

You should provide examples of the modern depictions of the Temple Mount you are referring to

Modern depictions of the temple do NOT show a single building but a central building surrounded by a series not porches and covered colonnades.

Does Jerusalem Temple at the Time of Jesus —YouTube count as a "modern depiction"?

@Ray Butterworth - Thanks for the referral at Youtube.  But notice that besides the Temple and Courts (Priest, women), that the rest of the Temple Mount  is shown as bare platform! (So also in other Youtube videos). Should there not be "buildings" there?

@raygrant - look at the numerous buildings including the covered colonnades!

@ Dottard - See the picture submitted by Dan Fefferman. There are NO Numerous Buildings shown in the Temple compound! Looks pretty bare! Also, if Jesus meant colonnades  would not He have said colonnades instead of "buildings"?

Many buildings or just One Sanctuary?The Greek word for "building" used in:
(a) Matthew 24:1-2 are oikodomas tou ieron (buildings of the temple), and(b)Mark 13:1, 2 are oikodomai (buildings); megalas oikodomas (great buildings)
This word for "building" conveys what we would normally consider a built ediface constructed in a usual way. Note that King Herod was not only famous for "killing his own family members" (and attempting to kill Jesus), but he was notorious for his many building projects throughout Judea: Herodium, Samaria, Caesarea sea port, Masada resort, etc. The Temple compound was the crown jewel on his building ambition list! He leveled the old City of David, added infill and massive retaining walls (450 feet high on Kedron Valley side) to build a platform for the Temple, built stables underneath the compound, cisterns, and much more.
It was mentioned in the Gospels that Herod had been working on this structure for 46 years at the time of Jesus. And it wasn't finished until 64 AD, just 6 years before it was all destroyed in 70 AD!
TempleThe Greek for "the Temple" is an interesting word. There are two words that are often translated "temple" in the New Testament:
(a) ho vaos This word refers to the Sacred ediface situated in the center of the Temple compound, and (b)  ieron This word referred to the whole Temple mount enclosure! [Henry Thayer,  GREEK-ENGLISH LEXICON OF N.T., 1974. Zondervan, p. 298-299, 422]
It is this second word delineating the whole enclosure that was used in our verses in question, so the discussion between Jesus and the Apostles  doesn't just deal with the Temple proper (Holy of holies, Holy place). The whole mount compound is in the questions that concerned the Apostles.
Temple EnclosureThe whole Temple mount was a "square 1,000 feet" (Alfred Edersheim, LIFE AND TIMES OF JESUS THE MESSIAH, P. 169), or approximately "35 acres" (K.E. Bailey, JESUS THROUGH MIDDLE EASTERN EYES, p. 232-233). To emphasize this size, consider that the whole city of Jerusalem was just 300 acres! (Edersheim, op. cit. p. 81)
The sacred Temple was situated inside. And was surrounded by "the Court of the Gentiles." The greatest size of this Court was on the west side of the Temple; lesser widths on the south and eastern side. (Edersheim, p. 169) Note that most modern pictorial depictions of the Compound do NOT show this correctly!
It was in this vast court that many shops, mart, and  sacrificial animal pens were kept. The shops of the High Priest family of Ananias (Anna) were operating here. And here the money-changers provided their "service". So the OPEN, VACANT COURTYARD most often shown in modern textbook drawings and scale models is quit misleading. It would be more accurate to picture the Courtyard as full of stores like a modern Mall or Flea Market crowded to the max with pilgrims, worshippers, and foreign gawkers.
What Conclusion?So what logical conclusion can we draw about Jesus's condemnation of the Temple and its pending destruction?
Knowing Herod's propensity to engage in rabid building projects, it is not unreasonable that several "buildings" along with the elaborate porticos could have been erected in the Temple Compound. Knowing that more activity ensued than just worship "within" the Temple sanctuary occurred, "buildings" to facilitate them are reasonable. And that the Greek word, ieron, was used in Matthew 24 (Temple enclosure), perhaps a modification in our modern drawings is in order. Perhaps...but let's not start another Denomination over it!

The OP does not specify which modern depictions it asks about. But here two possible answers:

Some modern depictions might focus only on the Temple proper and not the Temple compound. The NT term "buildings" probably counted annexes and defensive structures.

Some depictions could be of Solomon's or Zerubbabel's temple, rather than Herod's.


Note: this is a photo of the scale model of Herod's temple at the Israel Museum.


@ Dan Fefferman - Thank you for this beautiful picture. BUT here again, it is void of any "buildings" Jesus mentioned. Only the Temple structure alone is shown.  One would think that Jesus would just have said, "See this Temple...etc." And not mentioned "buildings." (plural)  Interesting. Peace.

@ Dan Fefferman - I forgot to mention that (a) the depictions I've examined did include both the Temple AND the compound encased by colonnades; (b) the pictures I've have seen are, by the captions, designating Herod's Temple, not the first Temple of Solomon. So perhaps there exists another mysterious reason for the voids(?)

There are multiple buildings in this picture. The main structure, the Heichal, in the middle is in a courtyard surrounding by other, smaller buildings. For example, you can see six towers in this picture. Those are separate buildings. They are part of the same compound but "buildings" make sense.

@ conceptualinertia - Thank you for your insight! To the occidental eye, "towers" seem to be "part of the wall structure"...not "separate buildings."  Perhaps to the oriental eye, these are buildings(?) Thanks for the suggestion.

@ conceptualinertia - Also notice that in the picture there is barely any space between the Temple and the Western Wall! According to Edersheim, this section had the widest space.  So another misrepresentation of the  Temple Enclosure.
